# Use of "die Babys" for kittens in North Germany?

Tags: word-usage, northern-german

Recently our cat gave birth to four kittens, which I referred to as "die Kätzchen" as does my native German wife (she's from Dresden). Yet every time I have heard any of the local populace talk about the kittens they use "die Babys" instead to the point they appear to be correcting me when I use "die Kätzchen". Is this a local dialectic difference, a bit of Plattdeutsch, actually what most people call kittens in Germany, or just people being cute (I wouldn't be too surprised to hear an English speaker call kittens "the babies" either)?

I live in rural Nordfriesland. Frisian is spoken in this area but, as far as I know, none of the people I have been speaking to speak Frisian.

Comment: I'd guess this is more about how society has changed during the last 20 years and pets are more and more impersonated and considered "close family members". That's IMHO, not a specifically German penomenom.

Comment: You can use 'baby' for animals in English too, especially when a more specific isn't known, for example "baby aardvark", or "the picture shows a mother aardvark and her babies". There are many factors which affect word choice beside region: spoken/written, formal/informal, the ages of the speaker and the listener. I'm pretty sure that in German you would spell it *Babys*. Fun fact: The 'German' word is *Säugling*; I don't know why someone thought importing a word from English was necessary.

Comment: Note that English loanwords in German form their plural according to German grammar. So it's "die Babys" not babies.

Comment: @Mitchell Spector: I went ahead and fixed both spelling issues. There are a few errors like this in English which spellcheck won't catch.

Comment: Thanks idmean and @RDBury. Yeah, I just used the spelling I was familiar with because I'd only heard it. In principle I know that is wrong but I forget :)

Comment: Am I the only person who saw this and thought 'who is telling babies to die?!?'?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaXigSu72A4. 'It means *the* Bart, *the*!'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Baby" is a usual word for "newly born" or "suckling". Usually it is used to refer to humans, but it can similarily be used to refer to newly born animals.

"Kätzchen" is just the deminuitive of "Katze", meaning 'small cat'.

The difference thus is more in what is more important to the speaker, the "being newly born" or the "being small cat".

A common word used specifically for infant animals is "das Junge (sg) / die Jungen (pl)".

That said, neither wording strikes me as particularily specific to any region (but I'm from NW Germany myself) and I could see myself using either, or maybe even "Baby-Kätzchen" to combine the former two while making sure to communicate that I'm talking about newly-born cats.

Comment: I would prefer *Junge*  see [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Junge#2) to *Kätzchen* (since it is shorter and easier to pronounce) and can't imagine to  use *Baby-Kätzchen*  when talking to somebody older than say four years. *Junge* is a universal term applicable to all animals and the context will already have been established in most cases, as in: *Unsere Katze hat vier Junge bekommen.*

Comment: Indeed, though I maintain that I could see myself still using "Baby-Kätzchen", being aware that it is the less formal word than 'Junge' and somewhat underlines the cuteness factor.

Comment: _Baby-Kätzchen_ is even a bit too redundant IMHO. I'd rather just say _Babykatzen_ myself.

Comment: With "das Junge" being an adjective made into a noun, the plural with a definite article would be "die Jungen".

Comment: @phipsgabler: For what it's worth, I'd consider "Katzenbabies" to sound much more natural than "Babykatzen". This impression is even stronger when generalizing the term to "Tierbabies" (common and natural) vs. "Babytiere" (not used at all?).

Comment: Also see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katzenjunges

Comment: Also note that in German you are supposed to put a hyphen between English and German parts of words, so it should be "Katzen-Babys", not "Katzenbabys", "Baby-Kätzchen", not "Babykätzchen", etc.

Comment: @ThomasHirsch das ist falsch, denn Baby wird inzwischen als deutsches Wort behandelt. Siehe https://www.dwds.de/wb/Baby

Comment: Du hast Recht, dass es falsch ist, aber die Begründung ist falsch. Jedes Fremdwort wird gleich richtig geschrieben und nicht erst mal falsch. Bindestriche setzt man, um bei Begriffen wie A-Säule oder T-Stück Klarheit zu schaffen. Mit Fremdwörtern haben sie nichts zu tun (außer in der Vorstellungswelt derer, die es falsch machen).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I agree. But note that that the *German* plural of "Baby" is "Babys". See http://www.neue-rechtschreibung.net/2009/09/16/plural-bei-englischen-fremdwortern-auf-y/.

Answer (score 4):

The proper term is "ein (Katzen-)Junges, mehrere Junge" (neuter).  Note that this is utterly different from "ein Junge, mehrere Jungen" (masculine) which means "a (human) boy, several boys" in most of Germany even though you'll find some mostly older people mostly in Bavaria insisting that the proper term for those would be "ein Knabe, mehrere Knaben".  A veterinary term may be "ein Katzenwelpe, mehrere Katzenwelpen" but "Welpe" on its own rather refers to infant canines, and use of that term outside of veterinary contexts would be unusual.